# How can I differentiate between capitalisation in a char?

Tags: if-statement

I want the user to also put a lowercase y into the system. How can I make it recognise it?
I apologise in advance if this question seems fairly basic, I'm still new to programming.

```
 Scanner end = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Do you want to quit the program? " +
        "Y - Yes/N - No");
 
      char endchar;
 
      endchar = endenext().charAt(0);
      if (end == 'Y') {
        break;
      }
```

Comment: `if (end == 'Y' || end == 'y') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add one more condition `end == 'y'` with OR operator.
example: `if (end == 'Y' || end == 'y')`

```
 Scanner end = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Do you want to quit the program? " +
        "Y - Yes/N - No");
 
      char endchar;
 
      endchar = endenext().charAt(0);
      if (end == 'Y' || end == 'y') {
        break;
      }
```

Comment: Or even short `endenext().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Character.toUpperCase()` function to convert the user input to an upper case letter. That way the capitalisation won't matter.

```
import java.lang.*;
...
Scanner end = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you want to quit the program? " + "Y - Yes/N - No");

char endchar;
endchar = Character.toUpperCase(endenext().charAt(0));
if (end == 'Y') {
   break;
}
```